# How to integrate TortoiseSVN and Maven

Tags: maven

I want to update my SVN repository using TortoiseSVN.

And I want to do this as part of maven pom.

The Maven SCM plugin needs command line svn tool.

I tried using exec-maven-plugin like

```
<executable>C:/Apps/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseProc.exe</executable>
<workingDirectory>C:/MDMSrc/trunk/venus/</workingDirectory>
<arguments>
    <argument>/command:update</argument>
    <argument>/path:"C:/MDMSrc/trunk/venus/"</argument>
    <argument>/closeonend:3</argument>
</arguments>
```

but I'm not sure how to attach this to a phase.

Comment: What does svn have to do with maven?

Comment: Apart from wrongly using the exec plugin and the relationship between SVN and Maven you can't use TortoiseProc as a command line tool, cause it's gui based. If you have Tortoise > 1.7.6 you can install the command line as well (but must be activated during installation of Tortoise) than you will get svn.exe etc.